# wordpress WooCommerce и php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется сайт на wordpress с плагином WooCommerce, на сайте имеются товары с ценой. Вопрос как на php вывести товар и его цену или где у плагина WooCommerce в базе данных хранится товар с ценой?

пытаюсь вывести товар вот так:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'product' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'nopaging' => true,
);

$query = new WP_Query;
$my_posts = $query->query($args);
print_r ($my_posts);
```

но в переменной my_posts цены товара нет, есть название, статус,дата публикации, описание. Рисунок 1. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

В метаданных хранится.

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
$sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
```

http://wpcheatsheet.net/woocommerce-get-price-in-custom-loop/

Answer (score 1):

В базу лезть не надо. На все существуют функции WooCommerce. В данном случае надо на основании номера поста создать объект `WC_Product` и из него получить цены:

```
foreach ($my_posts as $my_post) {
    $product = new WC_Product($my_post->ID);
    echo $product->get_regular_price();
    echo $product->get_sale_price();
    echo $product->get_price();
}
```